# Getting me off here - Is this the same as exciting sexually?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am surprised, because [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4776207125) says like this:

> Meaning of "please get me off here" is like "excite sexually".

This book proposed to say "please let me off here" instead of that.
I'm doubting this, because this book sometimes says untruthful things (Goobye is the same as "see you in hell!" etc.).

Getting me off here - Is this the same as exciting sexually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without context, I suppose it's ambiguous. At first, I understood it as "please let me off here/please drop me off here". I guess technically it can also be interpreted as the book suggests. We have

> [get off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_off)
>
> 8. (transitive with object following “get”, slang) To excite or arouse, especially in a sexual manner.
>      *Catwoman's costume really gets me off.*
> 9. (intransitive, slang) To experience an orgasm or other sexual pleasure; to become sexually aroused.
>      *You are not allowed to get off in my bedroom.*
>      *It takes more than a picture in a girlie magazine for me to get off.*

I'm assuming that what the book is trying to say is that *please let me off here* is correct as a request to exit a vehicle, like a taxi, whereas *please get me off here* is incorrect **and** that it has a sexual meaning to it. I agree that it is incorrect in the case. It doesn't make sense as a request to exit the taxi. But I'm not confident that it would be understood in a sexual manner. It doesn't really seem idiomatic when talking about *getting excited*, at least in AmE. In other words, I don't think *please get me off here* will be understood in an "excited" sense by most people, unless the surrounding context somehow supports this usage. Then it would likely mean getting one of the persons to orgasm.

Generally though, *get off* is used like in the example given in the entry above, *X gets me off*, where X is the thing from which excitement is derived. There is also the related *get off on*:

> [get off on sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-off-on-sth)
>   informal
>   -phrasal verb with get
>   to find something exciting, especially in a sexual way:
>   *Dave likes power - he gets off on it.*

*Please get me off here*, or *please get me off of here*, can be used to mean *please remove me from here* in a situation where you are ordering someone else to remove you, for example, while you're stuck on a broken roller coaster ride.

> Oh my god, the ride's stuck! Please get me off here now!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "get me off here" could be interpreted that way -- it comes from "getting off" which is definitely slang for being excited sexually. If it's in the context of asking to be dropped off at a certain location, then "please let me off here" would be better.

Most people probably wouldn't think about the sexual meaning if you said "please get me off here", but it will sound rather clumsy compared to "let me off here".

Interestingly however, something like "I'm getting off at the next stop" would never cross my mind as having a sexual meaning. Possibly because phrases like that are so common when on a bus/train/etc. that almost no one would think of any other meaning than "I'm leaving the bus/train/etc. at the next stop".

Comment: Well, technically "to get (someone) off" is to make them have an orgasm.  Figuratively it's used to say that something is an *orgasmic* experience.  Naturally not an expression to be used in "polite company" ... but then again what does that even mean nowadays?

Comment: Isn't it said when you're in a taxi or car, and you want to get out of it because you have reached your destination?

Comment: I think "I'm getting off at the next stop" works because there is no complicating indirect object **me**. It still could be heard as having a sexual connotation, but I agree it is not the natural interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "Please let me off here" is the proper phrase.  Basically you are asking politely to exit (allow me to leave) now.

The grammar is awkward to bad in "get me off".  You could grammatically request, "Please get me a hamburger." The word **hamburger** is a direct object, with **me** as indirect object. An understood **you** is the subject. But **off** does not fit as an object. If this were not an idiomatic phrase, the listener would hear the self-cancelling words and not know what you were talking about. Getting back to your question, yes, the phrase implies you would be asking someone to help you achieve sexual climax.

Strangely, the like-sounding phrase "turns me off" refers to something that reduces desire.